# Invalid argument: TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer. Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am getting the above error while training the models
I am training it on Google Colab

1. tensorflow version = 1.15
2. numpy version = 1.18.0

   !python3 object_detection/model_main.py \
   --pipeline_config_path=/content/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
   --model_dir=training/

I am totally new to tensorflow and not sure how to solve it. Can anyone please help me

This is error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Post the code where error occurred instead of giving link to notebook

Comment: @Rei Moriaty, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share the code to reproduce your issue so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors Yeah the problem has been solved. I changed my numpy version to 1.17.0.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the comments section, for the benefit of the community.

When the user has downgrade `numpy` version `1.18.0` to `1.17.0` has resolved the problem.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
!pip install numpy==1.17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

find where the linspace command is used in the code, the `num` variable needs to be passed as an integer. Shown in below answer:

```
np.linspace(0,1,int(10.))
```

Downgrading may not be required if one finds where linspace is used.